# Is there a way to tile from a selection in GIMP?

Tags: images, gimp, image-editing, tiles

Here's my goal. I have a texture sheet containing 256x256 textures, with "tile seamless" applied. However, each cell in the sheet is 512x512 so that the texture has 128 pixels of space on each side. I want to be able to tile each texture next to itself so that it fills the 128 pixels of space, while keeping the center 256x256 area the same.

In GIMP, the Filter -> Map -> Tile option only seems to do one thing, which is take the entire image and tile it. I don't want to do this, I only want to tile a small section of one image (so either from a selection or from the clipboard would work) and only apply the tile to the nearby area (I can also just isolate that area if it's applied to the whole image).

I'm using GIMP 2.10, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first item in the "Patterns" list in the "Clipboard". So you can use that to tile with the clipboard contents.

(this trick also works if you need the clipboard as a brush).